# ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCollectible' from 'brownie'

Tags: python, brownie

Implementing flask with brownie, to automate the the code create_collectible when hitting a button.
The import simple collectible is from this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/ZH_7nEIJDUY

Links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOVxkPvAHjI&t=776s
- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/views/

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/work/Documents/OpenvinoNFT/app/api/api.py", line 2, in <module>
    from create_collectible import main, nftcode
  File "/Users/work/Documents/OpenvinoNFT/app/api/create_collectible.py", line 4, in <module>
    from brownie import SimpleCollectible, account, network, config
ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCollectible' from 'brownie' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py)

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/work/Documents/OpenvinoNFT/app/api/api.py", line 2, in <module>
from create_collectible import main, nftcode
File "/Users/work/Documents/OpenvinoNFT/app/api/create_collectible.py", line 4, in <module>
from brownie import SimpleCollectible, account, network, config
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 359, in __call__
rv = self._load_unlocked()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 346, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 402, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 261, in locate_app
raise NoAppException(
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing 'api', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
File "/Users/work/Documents/OpenvinoNFT/app/api/api.py", line 2, in <module>
from create_collectible import main, nftcode
File "/Users/work/Documents/OpenvinoNFT/app/api/create_collectible.py", line 4, in <module>
from brownie import SimpleCollectible, account, network, config
ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCollectible' from 'brownie' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py)
```

Comment: The code in this post is much more useful than videos. Please transcribe whatever meaningful content in those videos into legible prose and code snippets here on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing the next:

In my flask app i added:

```
os.system("brownie run scripts/simple_collectible/create_collectible.py  --network rinkeby")
```

under my @app.route on flask.

The problem was that the code was running on the python CLI, and not in the Brownie CLI like it was supposed to.

It might not be the best way of doing it, but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the spelling to "SimpleCollectable" and install "brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation, you'll find what imports are available.

`SimpleCollectible` indeed is not there in the base module

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-brownie.html#brownie

Comment: The SimpleCollectible is a contract in solidity created by myself. 
If I run the code without flask, it runs!! It’s not that!

Comment: Well, if you're using python or flask command rather than `brownie` CLI options, it probably doesn't know how to load your contracts. I'm not familiar with these modules, but I suggest posting in the ethereum stackexchange to see if it's able to run a web server with your stuff

Comment: @Fpiantoni, if `SimpleCollectible` is something you created yourself, why are you trying to import it from the `brownie` module?  It would presumably be located somewhere in your own code.

Comment: @jasonharper Watch the video in the question... I assume running `brownie` command compiles the solidity contract into Python code, then manipulates the pythonpath to add it to the module import path. Running anything else like `python` or `flask` commands wouldn't do that

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `SimpleCollectible.sol` (I do not meant the code, I mean the file).

Then re-create it again with the relevant code in it.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the error you get, is that if you run the script using vs code directly, the contracts are not seen by brownie, you should instead run it from terminal using the command 'brownie run create_collectible'